# Android error in compiling tesswo ndk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Hello I am making an OCR using tesstwo library,I have imported the sample project from git and when i try to run the project Android Studio show the error, I am working on mac os 10.10

> /Users/sam/Development/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-application.mk
>   Error:(199) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':tesstwo:compileReleaseNdk'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sandeep/Development/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2.

Please help me to run the project successfully.

Comment: when tried same project and library in eclipse it is working fine.

Comment: I face the same error in my project, can you suggest me hows you solved this error in android studio.

Comment: @TejaDroid  try  sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }   in your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I have added following lines in **build.gradle** and after adding, the code complied successfully.

```
 sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
}
```